# Why do I get the following error when trying to install from mounted ISO in virtualbox?

Tags: mount, 14.04, virtualbox, software-installation

Information about my setup:
Windows 7x64
VirtualBox v4.3.10 r93012
DaemonTools (latest)
-Mounted Ubutnu 14.04 server installation ISO in DaemonTools
-Set DaemonTools virtual drive "E:" with the already mounted Ubuntu install image.

> The boot/Installation menu opens.  I select install Ubuntu Server, I
>   go through the keyboard detection process, then when it begins to
>   install at 2% progress I get the following error:
>
> There was a problem reading data from the CD-ROM.  Please make sure it
>   is in the drive.  If retrying does not work, you should check the
>   integrity of your CD-ROM.
>
> Failed to copy file from CD-ROM. Retry?
>
> Yes                    /                             No

Comment: Probably some bug with daemon tools. You use the iso directly , in vbox, set the iso as the cdrom.

Comment: This fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

check cd image by md5 checksum and compare it with checksum-file on server.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Comment: You boot the iso, not read from the iso.

Comment: Thank you bodhi.zazen... but I don't understand why this is always the go-to solution, why is the Ubuntu download so easily corrupted as compared to other downloadable programs/files?

Comment: The ubuntu .iso is no more or less prone to corruption then any other file and there are a number of variables, from networking errors to cd burning errors to problems with "installing" to a usb. If the cd / usb is not working, the first step in debugging the problem is to make sure the download was not corrupt. You will never get a corrupt download to work , so save a lot of time to advise checking the md5sum as one of the first steps.

Comment: Thank you bodhi.zazen.  I apologize if I sounded frustrated I have already begun the process as you recommended.  I'll give you an update soon.

Comment: Yes, oddly enough it was the installation file.  I just find it so strange that I can have two identical .iso's and only on works!  Crazy.

Comment: Sigh... so even after checking the md5, verifying that I have a good iso... I am still receiving the same error :(